# Interpolation still leaving NaN's (pandas groupby)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have a Dataframe with the location of some customers (so I have a column with Customer_id and others with Lat and Lon) and I am trying to interpolate the NaN's according to each customer.

For example, if I interpolate with the nearest approach here (I made up the values here):

```
 Customer_id   Lat    Lon
   A            1      1
   A            NaN    NaN  
   A            2      2      
   B            NaN    NaN
   B            4      4
```

I would like the NaN for B to be 4 and not 2.

I have tried this

```
series.groupby('Customer_id').apply(lambda group: group.interpolate(method = 'nearest', limit_direction = 'both'))
```

And the number of NaN's goes down from 9003 to 94. But I'm not understanding why it is still leaving some missing values.

I checked and these 94 missing values corresponded to records from customers that were already being interpolated. For example,

```
    Customer_id   Lat
 0.    A           1
 1.    A           NaN
 2.    A           NaN
 3.    A           NaN
 4.    A           NaN
```

It would interpolate correctly until some value (let's say it interpolates 1, 2 and 3 correctly) and then leaves 4 as NaN.

I have tried to set a limit in interpolate greater than the maximum number of records per client but it is still not working out. I don't know where my mistake is, can somebody help out?

(I don't know if it's relevant to mention or not but I fabricated my own NaN's for this. This is the code I used [Replace some values in a dataframe with NaN's if the index of the row does not exist in another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213009/replace-some-values-in-a-dataframe-with-nans-if-the-index-of-the-row-does-not-e/55213135#55213135)  I think the problem isn't here but since I'm very confused as to where the issue actually is I'll just leave it here)

Comment: sorry I'll change it in the question. I set it as a variable so that it was easier to change in the pipeline every time I run. But it was set to nearest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you interpolate with `nearest` it is only able to fill **in-between** missing values. (You'll notice this because you get an error when there's only 1 non-null value, like in your example). The remaining null values are  "edges" which are taken care of with `.bfill().ffill()` for the `nearest` logic. This is also the appropriate logic to "interpolate" with only one non-missing value.

```
def my_interp(x):
    if x.notnull().sum() > 1:
        return x.interpolate(method='nearest').ffill().bfill()
    else:
        return x.ffill().bfill()

df.groupby('Customer_id').transform(my_interp)

#   Lat  Lon
#0  1.0  1.0
#1  1.0  1.0
#2  2.0  2.0
#3  4.0  4.0
#4  4.0  4.0
```

Comment: Is this the case only for the nearest method? Cubic also gives me troubles should I try to do something similar with that approach too?

Comment: Typically interpolate is used to fill values in between. Outside values require you to extrapolate, which is typically done through curve fitting.

Comment: @Nocas see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491628/extrapolate-values-in-pandas-dataframe